# Are all operations in a Spring controller method part of the same Transaction?

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

This is the controller method in a controller class

```
@ApiOperation(value="Create a new employee")
            @ApiResponses({})
            @RequestMapping(value= "/createEmployee",method= RequestMethod.POST)
            public Callable<EmployeeDTO> createEmployee(
                    HttpServletRequest request,

                    @RequestBody @Valid final EmployeeDTO employeeDto) {
               long employeeId = employeeService.createEmployee(employeeDto);
              EmployeeDTO createdEmployee = employeeService.getEmployee(employeeId);
return () -> createdEmployee;
    }
```

This is the method for createEmployee(employeeDto) in the service class

```
   @Transactional
    public long createEmployee(employeeDto){
            Employee employee = new Employee();
            employee.setName(employeeDto.getName());
            employee.setCompanyId(employeeDto.getCompanyId());
            Employee savedEmployee = employeeRepository.save(employee);
            return savedEmployee.getEmployeeId();
    }
```

This is the getEmployee method in the same service class as above.

```
public EmployeeDTO getEmployee(long employeeId) {

        Employee employee = employeeRepository.findByEmployeeId(employeeId);

       EmployeeDTO employeeDTO = new EmployeeDTO();
       employeeDTO.setEmployeeId(employee.getEmployeeId());
       employeeDTO.setName(employee.getName());
   employeeDTO.setCompanyByCompanyId(employee.getCompanyByCompanyId());
    }
```

In the above code, will the employee object be persisted only after the controller method finishes execution? 
During debugging I see it is being inserted in the db. However, when accessing a referenced entity object, `employee.getCompanyByCompanyId()`it shows as NULL. So I am not sure if its because the persistence does not happen correctly or it is of some other reason. Please help.

Below are entity classes

```
 @Entity
        @Table(name = "employees")
        public class Employee {
            private long employeeId;
            private String name;
            private long companyId;
            private Company companyByCompanyId;

            @Id
            @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
            @Column(name = "employee_id")
            public long getEmployeeId() {
                return employeeId;
            }

            public void setEmployeeId(long employeeId) {
                this.employeeId = employeeId;
            }

            @Basic
            @Column(name = "name")
            public String getName() {
                return name;
            }

            public void setName(String name) {
                this.name = name;
            }

         @Basic
        @Column(name = "company_id")
        public long getCompanyId() {
            return companyId;
        }

        public void setCompanyId(long companyId) {
            this.companyId = companyId;
        }

            @ManyToOne
            @JoinColumn(name = "company_id", referencedColumnName = "company_id", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
            public Company getCompanyByCompanyId() {
                return companyByCompanyId;
            }

            public void setCompanyByCompanyId(Company companyByCompanyId) {
                this.companyByCompanyId = companyByCompanyId;
            }
        }
```

and a Company entity class like below

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "companies")
public class Company {
    private long companyId;
    private String companyName;
    private Collection<Employee> employeesByCompanyId;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "company_id")
    public long getCompanyId() {
        return companyId;
    }

    public void setCompanyId(long companyId) {
        this.companyId;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "company_name")
    public String getCompanyName() {
        return companyName;
    }

    public void setCompanyName(String companyName) {
        this.companyName = companyName;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "companyByCompanyId")
    public Collection<Employee> getEmployeesByCompanyId() {
        return employeesByCompanyId;
    }

    public void setEmployeesByCompanyId(Collection<Employee> employeesByCompanyId) {
        this.employeesByCompanyId = employeesByCompanyId;
    }
}   

public interface ExmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee,Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Employee> {

    Employee findByEmployeeId(long employeeId);
}
```

Comment: 1) Transaction context lives just inside createEmployee() method.

Comment: how are you saving company details in the DB, is it already present in the DB with the companyId which you referring the employee table call?

Comment: thanks @AmitKBist for your reply. yes, company is already present in the DB with the companyId

Comment: can you edit your qs with `findByEmployeeId()` method definition? I think you need to update this query to pull company data

Comment: I edited the qs and added that part. Basically I am using JPARepository interface to do my DB operations.